# Arithmetic on numbers provided by user

Tags: java, beginner, calculator

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CAI {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner cai = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Caluclator");

        System.out.println("\nHere are your options:");
        System.out.println("\n1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3. Division");
        System.out.println("4. Multiplication");

        System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to do?: ");
        int choice = cai.nextInt();
        System.out.println();


        if (choice == 1){
            addition();
        }
        else if (choice == 2){
            subtraction();
        }
        else if (choice == 3){
            division();
        }
        else if (choice == 4){
            multiplication();
        }

        System.out.println();
        cai.close();
    }

    public static void addition(){

        int One, Two;
        Scanner cai = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Addition");

        System.out.print("\nFirst Number: ");
        One = cai.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nSecond Number: ");
        Two = cai.nextInt();

        cai.close();
        System.out.println("\nSum: " + One + " + " + Two + " = " + (One + Two));
    }

    public static void subtraction(){
        int One, Two;
        Scanner cai = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Subtraction");

        System.out.print("\nFirst Number: ");
        One = cai.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nSecond Number: ");
        Two = cai.nextInt();

        cai.close();
        System.out.println("\nSum: " + One + " - " + Two + " = " + (One - Two));
    }

    public static void division(){
        int One, Two;
        Scanner cai = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Division");

        System.out.print("\nFirst Number: ");
        One = cai.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nSecond Number: ");
        Two = cai.nextInt();

        cai.close();
        System.out.println("\nSum: " + One + " / " + Two + " = " + (One / Two));
    }

    public static void multiplication(){
        int One, Two;
        Scanner cai = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Multiplication");

        System.out.print("\nFirst Number: ");
        One = cai.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nSecond Number: ");
        Two = cai.nextInt();

        cai.close();
        System.out.println("\nSum: " + One + " x " + Two + " = " + (One * Two));
    }
}
```

ok So i have this project for a class and what i am trying to do is make addition questions that would pick the numbers i chose randomly and make questions out of them, i am also trying to have the user to write the answer and let them know if the answer they chose is right or wrong. I know its a lot to ask but my project is due in 2 hours and i need help

Comment: On this site we only review working code. I suggest you have a look at the [guidelines](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: should work right now

Comment: Keep in mind that, while we will review the code you posted for possible improvements, we will not write code for the rest of your assignment.

Comment: If you switch the code with the context you will draw more attention to your question because it won't look so weird on the frontpage.

Answer (score 1):

### Validating user input

The way that you capture user input is quite brittle. While it will work fine as long as the user knows they should only input integers, it's ***never safe*** to assume that users will provide valid input:

```
What would you like to do?:  hello
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

We first need to handle this `InputMismatchException` for cases where the user enters an invalid value, by using [`try-catch`](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/):

```
try {
    choice = cai.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```

This is not quite right yet, though; even though it handles the exception and prevents a program crash, we need to not leave this block until we actually have input we can use. So let's introduce a validation condition and a `while` loop:

```
int choice = 0;
boolean inputIsInteger = false;
while (!inputIsInteger) {
    System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to do?: ");
    try {
        choice = cai.nextInt();
        inputIsInteger = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
        System.out.println("Input must be an integer.");
        cai.next();
    }
}
```

Now, that works pretty well:

```
What would you like to do?:  hello
Input must be an integer.

What would you like to do?:  1

Addition
```

You may think: *"But, that seems like a lot of code to handle one single user input!"*

And you would be right! Fortunately, `Scanner` has a built-in method `hasNextInt()` that does this in a much simpler way:

```
System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to do?: ");
while (!cai.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Input must be an integer.");
    cai.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nTry again: ");
}
int choice = cai.nextInt();
```

This way our Scanner will keep looping until it finds a valid `int` in the input buffer, making it safe to then call `nextInt()`.

---

So far, so good. Now, I noticed that you are needing to get integer inputs everywhere in your code... We could save us a lot of copying and pasting of the above code by making a method that does this for us:

```
private static int getIntInput(Scanner sc) {
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Input must be an integer.");
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nTry again: ");
    }
    return sc.nextInt();
}
```

Then, each time we need to scan for an int, we just call it with an instance of `Scanner`:

```
System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to do?: ");
int choice = getIntInput(cai);
```

---

You should also validate that the input is usable according to your program logic, for instance that the `choice` is a valid choice (i.e. 1 - 4) otherwise ask the user for valid input. This should be easily done using another while loop or some similar construct.

```
boolean isValidChoice = false;
int choice = 0;
while (!isValidChoice) {
    System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to do?: ");
    choice = getIntInput(cai);
    if (choice > 0 && choice <= 4) {
        isValidChoice = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nChoose an option from 1 to 4: ");
    }
}

if (choice == 1){
    addition();
}
// etc...
```

---

#### Other things

Here are some other concerns & suggested improvements on the code.

- Consider moving your menu selection out of `main` and into its own method, like `calculatorMainMenu()` and call that when you need it.
- The `(One / Two)` calculation in your `division()` method can result in [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) due to possible division-by-zero error. You should validate `Two` to make sure that `0` is never acceptable as input.
- Consider using a [`switch` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead of a lot of `if-else` for things like your menu, where you're just comparing a variable against some constants.
- Naming an instance of `Scanner` as `cai` is pretty odd. Writing something like `scanner` or `sc` for short is much more commonplace.
- The names `One` and `Two` are also a bit odd. Something like `num1` and `num2` would be better, I think, to make it simple and clear that there's no particular significance to them other than the order in which they appear.
- `"Caluclator"` should be spelled `"Calculator"`
- Only the result of an addition is called "sum". To be correct, you should use "difference" for subtraction, "product" for multiplication, and "quotient" for division.

Comment: I'm not including another answer as I only have 2 more suggestions - making `addition` and it's brethren pure functions accepting 2 parameters and returning the result, and putting the whole `switch` in `calculatorMainMenu` inside a `do{...}while(...);` to make the calculator more REPL-y (with a `default` to handle invalid choices.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the input validation and code structure concerns expressed by Phrancis, you basically repeat the code for the four arithmetic methods four times. The only differences are the strings for input / output and the actual calculation. This is definitively code smell.

So, basically you should plug in the variable parts and write the method once.

Various strategies come to mind as to how this can be achived. Let's start off with simple object-oriented and inheritance. Make an abstract base class which contains a few callbacks:

```
public abstract class ArithmeticOperation {
    public void doCalculation() {
        int One, Two;
        Scanner cai = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(getTitle());

        System.out.print("\nFirst Number: ");
        One = cai.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nSecond Number: ");
        Two = cai.nextInt();

        cai.close();
        System.out.println("\nSum: " + One + getOperationSign() + Two + " = " + calculate(One, Two));
    }

    protected abstract String getTitle();
    protected abstract String getOperationSign();
    protected abstract int calculate(int first, int second);
}
```

Then, create subclasses:

```
public class Addition extends ArithmeticOperation {
    protected String getTitle() {
        return "Addition";
    }

    protected abstract String getOperationSign() {
        return "+";

    protected abstract int calculate(int first, int second) {
        return first + second;
    }
}
```

... and so on. Then use

```
new Addition().doCalculation();
```

instead of the methods.

Second approach: plugging this into a structure (I like to use enums here).

Note: This topic will be a little more advanced... ;-)

Having a complete class hierarchy to basically hold records like `("Additon", "+", +)` and `("Multiplication", "x", *)` seems a little unwieldy, thus we should be able to write this a little shorter. No problem with the two strings, but the "active" (the actual operators) part poses a problem, as you cannot evaluate an expression along the lines of

```
num1 myOperatorVariable num2
... with myOperatorVariable being "+" or something
```

Fortunately, Java 8 gave us lambda expressions, so you can write

```
(num1, num2) -> num1 + num2
```

And store this in a variable. (The variables type is `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>` in our case.)
Thus, the following code snippet works:

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> myOperator = (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2;
int result = myOperator.apply(1, 2);
// result is 3 now
```

Putting it all together, using an enum:

```
public enum Operator {
    ADD("Addition", "+", (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2),
    SUBTRACT("Subtraction", "-", (n1, n2) -> n1 - n2),
    // ... rest left as an exercise ;-)
    ;
    public final String title;
    public final String operationSign;
    public final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> operation;

    private Operator(String title, String operationSign, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> operation) {
        this.title = title;
        this.operationSign = operationSign;
        this.operation = operation;
    }
}
```

... and to use this, pass this as a parameter to a general calculation function:

```
public void doCalculation(Operator op) {
    int One, Two;
    Scanner cai = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(op.title);

    System.out.print("\nFirst Number: ");
    One = cai.nextInt();

    System.out.print("\nSecond Number: ");
    Two = cai.nextInt();

    cai.close();
    System.out.println("\nSum: " + One + op.operationSign + Two + " = " + op.operation.apply(One, Two));
}
```

Generally, whenever you find yourself copying and pasing code, something is wrong and you should find a different solution.